# Basis of $\mathbb{R}^2_{\rm discrete}$ with the lexicographic order topology

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have a homework problem that asks us to find the basis $\mathbb{R}^2_{\rm discrete}$ with the lexicographic order topology. I actually have no idea, so any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What class are you taking?

Comment: General Topology.

Comment: Does this help? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/789720/is-mathbbr2-lexicographic-cong-mathbbr-discrete-times-mathbbr

Comment: Kinda. The question is not the same. It's helpful tho. Thanks :)

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure exactly what you're asking.  Do you want to find the basis *of* $\mathbb{R}^2_\text{discrete}$ with the lexicographic order topology?

Comment: Exactly what I'm trying to find.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the notation $\mathbb{R}^2_{\rm discrete}$.  Care to explain?

Comment: @RyanSinclair: The notation $\Bbb R^2_{\rm discrete}$ is rather odd. The lexicographic order topology on $\Bbb R^2$ is not the discrete topology on $\Bbb R^2$, nor is it $(\Bbb R_{\rm discrete})^2$ (which in any case is just $\Bbb R^2$ with the discrete topology). So what exactly do you mean by $\Bbb R^2_{\rm discrete}$?